# Route not defined when using 'auth' flter

Tags: authentication, laravel, laravel-4, routes

I've started playing around with Laravel. I want to create simple authentication logic using 'auth' filter for my route. The problem is when I set the route like this:

```
Route::get('/user', array('before' => 'auth', 'as' => 'user', function() {
    return Redirect::action('UserController@index');
}));

Route::get('/login', 'UserController@login');
```

I get: **[InvalidArgumentException] - Route [UserController@index] not defined**

However, when I go with a basic route:

```
Route::get('/user', 'UserController@index');
```

the page renders successfully.

Can anyone see the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try adjusting the route to use `UserController@index`

```
Route::get('/user', array(
    'before' => 'auth',
    'as' => 'user',
    'uses' => 'UserController@index'
));
```